# get one row of dummy data with eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, dummy-data

Take this example

```
$result = Players::select("first_name", "last_name")->where("some_field", "some_value");
```

That returns a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`

Now I would like to "simulate" that same thing but with dummy data, so I did this

```
$result = Players::select(DB::raw("'john', 'doe'"));
```

That works, but when the query runs, if the the players table has 10 rows I get 10 rows filled with john doe and I only need just one.

I've tried doing

```
$result = Players::select(DB::raw("'john', 'doe'"))->limit(1);
```

but that has no effect

How can I get only 1 row of dummy data? Taking into account that `$result` must return a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it in your suggested way i think this should work :

```
$result = Players::select(DB::raw("'john' as first_name , 'doe' as last_name"))->take(1);
```